# Setting Konqueror-style access keys for links in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, accessibility, konqueror

In [Konqueror](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konqueror), if I press the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, I get boxes with letters in them for every link and button on the page:

[image: Konqueror with access links]

I believe this is called an ["access key"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_key), but it is done *without* the original webpage having a ton of [access key attributes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_key#Specifying_access_keys). Konqueror just creates access keys for all the links.

How can I enable similar behavior in Chrome, either natively or with an add-on?

Comment: I cannot get these links when I press the `Ctrl` key. I am on Manjaro Linux if that matters. How do I enable this feature for Konqueror, assuming that it this feature is still present after 12 years?

Comment: You can use [vimium](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vimium/dbepggeogbaibhgnhhndojpepiihcmeb?hl=en) on a chrome based browser.  I don't use Konqueror myself, anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found something!  [Vimium](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vimium/dbepggeogbaibhgnhhndojpepiihcmeb?hl=en) for Chrome.

"Vimium is a Google Chrome extension which provides keyboard shortcuts for navigation and control in the spirit of the Vim editor."

Hat tip to [this answer](http://fogbugz.stackexchange.com/questions/4310/keyboard-shortcuts/8429#8429) on fogbugz stackexchange.

Press <kbd>F</kbd> to get:

[image: link example with Vimium]